# Why flex content affects positioning of unrelated elements outside flex in Chrome and IE?

Tags: css, flexbox

I’ve noticed some unexpected layout behaviour of flex content, namely it affects positioning of the unrelated elements on the page.

Scenario: I have div.container and div.content inside. div.container has the display set to inline-flex and centres div.content vertically.

Now, any content (that uses regular flow) I put after the container can’t go higher than the top of div.content.

When I add some free text after the div.container, it is aligned with the div.content top, even though it is completely outside the flex container and should be unrelated to it.

When I add another div.container, it is positioned the way its div.content is no higher that div.content of the previous, unrelated div.container. This container (or rather its div.content) in turn affects the position of the subsequent ones.

https://flex-content-affects-outside.stackblitz.io/

It looks as if the top of a div cannot be placed higher than the top of divs before it in the document flow.

In my case, this doesn’t affect inline-flex containers directly, but rather their content. The vertical position of the flex containers if affected as the result – so that their content is aligned.

This behaviour is visible in Chrome and IE11. On the other hand, in Firefox everything works as expected.

My question is: What causes such a behaviour? Is it in any way standardized?

In the example above isn’t a significant problem, we can wrap all the boxes in another flex to get the expected behaviour. However, I’m afraid that in more complex layouts some unexpected relations between seemingly independent content can ruin the layout.

Edit: I'm adding a code snippet.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container .content {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Content.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: vertical-align:top`

Answer (score 0):

As Paulie_D noticed in the comment, it was caused by vertical-align. Once we specify vertical-align: top everything works as expected.

```css
.container {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.container .content {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(200, 200, 200, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Content.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
  </div>
</div>
```

Or, more elaborate one:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-content-affects-outside-baseline-elwwvc?file=style.scss

More precisely, the layout was due to the implicit vertical-align:baseline (in Chrome and IE). The boxes are inline-flex and there were laid out according to the baseline. Once we specify this explicitly the behaviour is consistent among browsers. Another font size in one of the boxes makes it more visible.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/flex-content-affects-outside-baseline?file=style.scss